# How can I use Groovy classes in other packages without JAR?

Tags: groovy, classpath

I'm pretty new to Groovy (coming from Java), so this may be a stupid question  :-)

Nonetheless: I'd like to structure a couple of Groovy scripts using packages. And I'd like to import some general Groovy classes from some other package.

How can I make sure that my Groovy scripts finds the other classes in the other packages? The only classpath related files I can remember are JARs.

Comment: If you from java. Groovy loads classes as java, but includes non-compiled with extension `.groovy`. So, you have to place your classes relative to classpath according to their package name.

Comment: So I would `cd` to the source folder and then call e.g. `com.foo.bar.MyScript.groovy`  ?

Comment: i don't know your folder organization. but it should be something like this: `groovy -cp "path_to_classes" "path_and_name_of_main_groovy_script"`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works! Please post your comment as answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you from java:

Groovy loads classes as java and also includes non-compiled with extension `.groovy`.

So, you have to place your classes relative to classpath according to their package name.

The command line should be something like this:

```
groovy -cp "path_to_classes_root" "path_and_name_of_main_groovy_script.groovy"
```